# Saliency Mesh Computation/Interest Point Detection in Python

Tags: python, computer-vision, 3d-object-detection

I want to calculate salient vertices in a 3D mesh, meaning those points, that are of interest. This paper https://doi.org/10.1007/s00371-015-1199-3 describes well, what I would like to achieve. Moreover, I need a python implementation. I already took a look at `trimesh` and `gaussian_curvatures` but the results weren't that great. Maybe I should rather look for 3D-Descriptors?

I'm happy for any hints, whether its documentation, pseudocode, or actual code for the implementation.